# How can I register my WP device in dev account?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have trouble with registration WP8.1 device to developer account. My account is active. Device early was active, but I reset phone (Nokia 620) and after that Developer tools don't active this phone.
In list (in dev acc) this phone was remove.
[image]

after I press "register" show this window:

[image]

and that's all. Second window close after few seconds and register process don't finish. Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your computer have internet connection. I had similar issue when network proxy was configured incorrectly .

Also try after clearing internet explorer cached content (history,password,cookies etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work. I really have incorrect proxy server.